# How to handle filenotfound condition in java agent running and reading files 24*7

Tags: java

I am having application which runs 24*7
Its java standalone application. it reads log file  line by line from configured location.
When it doesn't find log file, then it just put exception statck trace in its own log file and again the loop continues.
It keeps logging "File not Found exception log" till it finds some at the given location.
I want it to stop for some time and then retry. For this to achieve, is it good idea to sleep thread for say 30 or 40 mins?
If I throw exception and stops agent in such case I have no way or any monitor which will start agent again.

plz suggest some solution in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, I think it is a good idea to preserve resources and make the application sleep for a while and check again. Don't keep dumping the same stack over and over, just the first and the last time would be good enough, until some other condition comes along.